# Why does this code make sense?

Tags: php

This is the code

```
<p>We are going to flip a coin until we get three heads in a row!</p>

<?php
$headCount = 0;
$flipCount = 0;
while ($headCount < 3) {
    $flip = rand(0, 1);
    $flipCount ++;
    if ($flip) {
        $headCount ++;
        echo "<div class=\"coin\">H</div>";
    } else {
        $headCount = 0;
        echo "<div class=\"coin\">T</div>";
    }
}
echo "<p>It took {$flipCount} flips!</p>";
?>
```

I've played around with Java but I'm now learning PHP. The part that doesn't make sense right here is this.

```
if ($flip) {
    $headCount ++;
    echo "<div class=\"coin\">H</div>";
}
```

What exactly is being checked here? I doubt it's checking whether `$flip` is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a common shorthand in these kinds of languages. Once you get used to it, it seems natural.

In this case,

```
if ($flip)
```

is equivalent to:

```
if ($flip == 1)
```

But PHP is really just checking for a "truthy" value: `true`, not zero, not `"0"` or `""`, not `[]`, and others will evaluate as `true` and pass the `if ($flip)` test.